# How to proxy pass two applications running on / on two different ports

Tags: nginx

this is my nginx configuration file

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 0.0.0.0;
        client_max_body_size 10000M;
        location / {
                auth_basic "Restricted Content";
                auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/.htpasswd;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-Scheme $scheme;

                # WebSocket support
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_read_timeout 120s;
                proxy_next_upstream error;
        }
        location /source {
                auth_basic "Restricted Content";
                auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/.htpasswd;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5050/source;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-Scheme $scheme;

                # WebSocket support
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_read_timeout 120s;
                proxy_next_upstream error;

           }
}
```

I am able to route first application running on port 8888 but for second application running on port 5050 i am not able to route through nginx. i am using /source as a prefix but it's not working. Second application also starts with / in our application. Please request guidance in this on the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

`/` matches before `/source` so you never reach `/source` and therefore can't be routed. switching the order of the `location` directive should be enough.

Comment: tried that but no luck. It won't connects